# Netcat bidirectional communication

Tags: ubuntu, netcat

The goal which I am attempting to achieve is for a client to send the following command to a server:

```
echo "Hello" | nc IP Port
```

Upon receiving the "Hello" keyword, the server which is listening using:

```
nc -nlp port
```

should then send a response "Holla" back to the client. I have tried the following, none of which work in my instance:

- [run a command conditionally with netcat and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990099/run-a-command-conditionally-with-netcat-and-grep)
- [Is a conditional response possible with netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743304/is-a-conditional-response-possible-with-netcat)
- [How to respond conditionally based on the request when using netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40081779/how-to-respond-conditionally-based-on-the-request-when-using-netcat)

So the issue which I am currently facing is that upon receiving the "Hello" from the client side, the server side is unable to send a "Holla" response back to the client. Is there a way to do this with netcat? If so what am I missing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need some `bash` magic and some FIFO to achieve that, but it's totally doable:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# Communication diagram:
# 
# +----------+          +------------+
# |          |  stdout  |            |   
# |    nc    | =======> | _feed_fifo |
# |          |          |            |
# +---stdin--+          +------------+
#      /\                ||
#      ||                || $fifo_ref 
#      ||                \/
#  +--stdout----------stdin-+
#  |                        |
#  |   __handle_fifo_data   |
#  |                        |
#  +------------------------+

fifo_ref="$RANDOM.fifo"
running_lock="$RANDOM.run"

# Strip leading and trailing white space (new line inclusive).
trim() {
    [[ "$1" =~ [^[:space:]](.*[^[:space:]])? ]]
    printf "%s" "$BASH_REMATCH"
}

# Handles data coming from the nc, with it's stdout connected
# directly to the client.
__handle_fifo_data() {
    # Keep trying to read the fifo while it exists
    while test -e "$1"
    do
        while read -r line
        do
            # This is where the magic happens. Anything sent to stdout will
            # be transmitted to the client connected to the nc
            echo "handling $line" >&2 # this is how we debug what's coming

            # Lines will include a \r in the end if coming from telnet.
            # Stripping the line from unwanted characters in the beginning/end
            # (line breaks, spaces, etc).
            message="$(trim "$line")"
            
            # Responding only if the message is "Hello"
            [ "$message" == "Hello" ] && {
                echo "Hola!"
            }
        done < $1 # feeding the loop with our fifo
    done
}

# Will read input and feed the fifo so we can handle data
__feed_fifo() {
    # This is important, otherwise we'll trash the terminal with lots of 
    # bash pids trying to read a dead stdin
    while test -e "$1"
    do
        # Testing again in case of concurrency
        test -e "$1" && cat - > "$1"
    done
}

# Cleaning up if something goes south or the program simply ends
trap "rm -rf ${fifo_ref} ${running_lock}" EXIT INT TERM HUP

# Let's get this party started
touch "$running_lock"

# Won't stop until you say so
while test -e "$running_lock"
do
    # Let's clear out the fifo so we don't get dirt from previous connections
    test -e "${fifo_ref}" && rm -rf "${fifo_ref}"
    mkfifo "${fifo_ref}"

    # Netcat port 9999
    # We'll feed the nc using our __handle_fifo_data and read from it to a
    # __feed_fifo which will try to keep stdin open all the time, feeding
    # __handle_fifo_data
    nc -l 9999 \
        0< <(__handle_fifo_data "${fifo_ref}") \
        1> >(__feed_fifo "${fifo_ref}")
done
```

You can test it by saving it to something like `server.sh` and running in one session:

```sh
$ bash -x ./server.sh
handling Hello
```

And in other session:

```sh
$ telnet localhost 9999
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello
Hola!
^]
telnet> Connection closed.
```

To stop it just `^C`

Comment: How could be if I want to send the command `quit` instead of `Hello`, and the connection will close? Great answer, but the way. Parabens!

Comment: Well, I got what I need. Just added this line => `pkill -x nc > /dev/null 2>&1` and adjust some others. You can see an example on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/robe007/23be35b2b26bdd86ef8d124bfa2d2282)

Comment: Cool solution! Keep in mind only that the `pkill` could also kill other `netcat` instances that you might be running alongside your `server.sh`