# Netcat - echoing responses from server

Tags: netcat

I need to `echo` whatever the client listens/get on a port, back to that same port. My question is, if that's possible with `Netcat` and if so how?

I don't use netcat much, and I've searched and couldn't find a solution.

This was the closest thing I found, but it didn't help: [netcat: send text to echo service, read reply then exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332163/netcat-send-text-to-echo-service-read-reply-then-exit)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900864/netcat-bidirectional-communication/64186214#64186214) could help you

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like:

```
$ nc -kl 8080
```

The option `-k` forces `nc` to stay listening for another connection after its current connection is completed.

For testing, once you have `nc` running on another terminal run:

```
$ curl 0:8080
```

or

```
$ telnet 0 8080
```

on the terminal you have `nc -kl 8080` running, you will see all the incoming data, besides typing and also send data back